# Can't replace \ or escape character in string in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string with backslash or escape character and curly braces. I am trying to replace these backslash or escape character and curly braces with an empty string using this code:

```js
const regex = /[{}\\]/g
const s = "<speak>time=\"500ms\"/></speak>{1}";
console.log(s.replaceAll(regex, ''));
```

I am expecting this as the output:

```
<speak>time="500ms"/></speak>1
```

The code works on all web editors I have tried, but not during runtime in actual code. The code replaces the curly braces during runtime but not the backslash or escape character. Is there anything that stands out as wrong?

Comment: `s` doesn't contain a backslash: `console.log(s)` . When JavaScript interprets the string *literal* it interprets the escape sequence `\"` as `"`. The actual string *value* only contains `"`.

Comment: Note that the String.prototype.replaceAll() method was added in ES2021/ES12.

Comment: How are you observing the result?  In any console I've used, when outputting a string value, it wraps the string values in quotes.  Which means it needs to *add* backslashes for quote characters to make it a valid literal.  The string value in the code shown doesn't actually contain any backslashes, that's just the syntax of the string literal.

Answer (score -1):

> The code works on all web editors I have tried

Because [`replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) **As of August 2020** [Modern browsers have support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) it!

> but not during runtime

I think in runtime env you run an old version of node!
So install version NodeJS 15+ which [support](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v15.0.0/#v8-8-6-35415) `replaceAll` method!

Or you could just use only replace with *flag* `g` which do same as `replaceAll`

```js
const regex = /(<.*?>|[\{\}])/g
const s = "<speak>time=\"500ms\"/></speak>{1}";
console.log(s.replace(regex, ''));//time="500ms"/>1
```

Comment: I've tried replace too with no success. Also the node version running on my environment is 16.16.0

Comment: what's the output do you expect?

Comment: time="500ms"/>1